# sphinx autodoc include subfunctions

Tags: python, python-sphinx, autodoc

I want to automatically include subfunctions of a function in the sphinx documentation. What is the option for this?

My code looks like

```
import numpy
def mainfunc():
    """ to be documented 

    """

    def subfunc():
        """ to be documented as well

        """
```

By now I set in the included `code.rst`

```
Code Reference
==============

.. automodule:: lqgbt_lnse
   :members:
```

But the output by sphinx includes only the mainfunction.

Comment: No user will have access to `subfunc()`, so it makes sense that its docstring is not part of the public documentation.

Comment: I'm facing same issue, did you find a way to do so ?

Comment: No. :( But I thought that @NicoSchlömer was quite right with his comment.